# How to create multiple collapsible cards in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to create multiple collapsible card in angular. I am facing one issue when I click on any card it opens us all the cards  could any please tell me how I will solve this issue.

Following is the link of my code sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-nash-f1dwu

Answer (score 1):

This is because you use the same variable for both cards. So when you click on the card the value of the variable changes and open both cards.
On your example I guess the most efficient way would be to add a second `visible` variable. So you can then just trigger the corresponding variable on the card click event.

The second solution would be to store the state of your list of cards in an array.
I edited your code to this solution:
https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-hofstadter-jj4kl

Or third solution could be to make an own component with the card content and the corresponding `visible` state. Then you have your own scope within your component, so you don't overwrite it when you click on an other card.
View this example of you code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-carson-tbg25

But anyway you need to store the state of each card anywhere.

Does this help?

Comment: is there any other way to fix it

Comment: I edited my original answer with an other way to fix it.

Comment: thanks for you suggestion but I cannot loop the data

Comment: I added a third solution, maybe this does help?

Comment: could you please show me how can I add second visible variable

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are using the same variable in your `app.component.ts` to open the cards. You are calling the same `showContent()` and `hideContent()` functions for both cards that set `this.visible` variable to true or false, so whenever your variable gets setted to true or false both cards open / close.

You have 2 different approaches to fix this. You can set different variables to each card or, if you are using bootstrap, you can use this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example .